# Operate/control host hardware from within docker container

Tags: docker

Is there a way to to control a hardware interface (in my case it's an acquisition interface providing a stream of numerical values) from within the docker container?

Until now I was running a binary in the host system executing calls to a shared library which controlled the acquisition interface. Now I have to integrate the whole App in a container...

One of the possibilities I was thinking of, is to write the stream to a file in the ramfs and read it from docker, but its not really an elegant solution.
I should be able if possible, to stop, restart, change the sampling rate, etc... of the acquisition card and of course buffer the data.

Any ideas are welcome!!

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be accomplished with some sort of networking, like f.e. containers communicate with each other. Sorry cannot put exact example since question is broad and not so specific

Comment: By networking you mean for example communication via sockets (Unix sockets, zeromq, etc...)? If yes, I've already thought about it, but in my precise case, I believe the data amount is too high to be handled this way...